# wkhtmltopdf and zurb fundation

Tags: php, laravel, wkhtmltopdf

I have problem with link wkhtml with css from zurb fundation framework 5. I use laravel and in myhtml I have absolute url to css.

Pdf is ok but without layout from css.

Any ideas?

I tried also with local css in html file.

Comment: You need to render both pdf and html, or only pdf ?

Comment: only pdf but I need use blade template as base for html

Answer (score 0):

you can use [helpers](http://laravel.com/docs/helpers#paths) in your links

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" 
href="{{public_path().'/assets/css/fo.css'}}" />
```

Comment: I'm not sure. But I'm afraid that zurb is not support by pdf converters. Because I tired also mPDF and dompdf. 

I have one problem. All div with class collumn and eg. large-4 are ignored and listed as block not inline.

Comment: It's strange, because if I  set url from any website css is imported. I added my html as url and in pdf is html but still without zurb columns import.

Comment: I had the same problem with boostrap, I replace all class div with `.col-xs-`, I don't know about foundation but according to this post (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20333666/how-to-accomplish-what-bootstrap-grid-system-does-with-its-col-xs-or-small) you may try with `small-`, some explanation here for bootstrap (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19705880/converting-twitter-bootstrap-page-into-pdf-with-wkhtmltopdf-span-issue)

Comment: wkhtmltopdf didn't support css in @media block, and I think 'all' grid in foundation are inside @media block. So you need to write your "own" grid => just remove `@media`

Comment: thanks, you have right. It's media problem. I added .large and .column and works good.

Comment: I added + to you comment. But I can't accept answer above because, someone can be confuse.

Answer (score 0):

1. create css folder in " public " and put all css files in it.
2. now to include css file use this :

   `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url('css/filename.css')}}" />`